# Combine one column's values into a single string

Tags: sas

This might sound awkward but I do have a requirement to be able to concatenate all the values of a char column from a dataset, into one single string. For example:

```
data person;
   input attribute_name $ dept $;
   datalines;
John Sales
Mary Acctng
skrill Bish
;
run;
```

Result : test_conct = "JohnMarySkrill"
The column could vary in number of rows in the input dataset.
So, I tried the code below but it errors out when the length of the combined string (samplkey) exceeds 32K in length.

```
DATA RECKEYS(KEEP=test_conct);
length samplkey $32767;

do until(eod); 
    SET person END=EOD;
    if lengthn(attribute_name) > 0 then do;
       test_conct = catt(test_conct, strip(attribute_name));
       end;
    end;
output; stop;
run;
```

Can anyone suggest a better way to do this, may be break down a column into chunks of 32k length macro vars?

Regards

Comment: Are you trying to build yourself a list for filtering via Pass through SQL or something else?

Comment: A bunch of different options are suggested and coded here: https://communities.sas.com/t5/New-SAS-User/Using-INTO-to-create-a-macro-variable-for-pass-through-teradata/m-p/555231/highlight/true#M9637

Comment: Maximum length of SAS character variables is 32K.  If the message (the concatenation of values in column) is longer than that you will need to write out a file and use an external utility such as Perl, R, Python or Powershell in order to compute the digest.

Comment: @Richard - So, are we saying we have no option in SAS to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

It would very much help if you indicated what you're trying to do but a quick method is to use SQL

```
proc sql NOPRINT;
select name into :name_list separated by ""
from sashelp.class;
quit;

%put &name_list.;
```

As you've indicated macro variables do have a size limit (64k characters) in most installations now. Depending on what you're doing, a better method may be to build a macro that puts the entire list as needed into where ever it needs to go dynamically but you would need to explain the usage for anyone to suggest that option. This answers your question as posted.

Try this, using the VARCHAR() option. If you're on an older version of SAS this may not work.

```
data _null_;
set sashelp.class(keep = name) end=eof;
length long_var varchar(1000000);
length want $256.;

retain long_var;

long_var = catt(long_var, name);

if eof then do;
want = md5(long_var);
put want;
end;


run;
```

Comment: I need to do a md5 function on the clubbed value of the column.

Comment: My SAS engine does not support varchar option. However I have tried a code, will post it below, but it still throws an error, will share details there.

Comment: You need to use DS2 to use VARCHAR data type.

Comment: @Tom even if you're not storing that data type in the data step?

Comment: Without the PROC DS2 wrapper the data step will just use old style SAS which just has floating point numbers and fixed length character vars limited to 32767 bytes.

Comment: I'm on SAS 9.4 M4 , it does not seem to support this functionality of varchar since even after using it, it still throws the same error. I've added that code in the separate answer that I have added within this post.